# Show options menu button on Galaxy Nexus (Android 4.1)

Tags: android, galaxy-nexus

I am using options menu in my app. But when I install the app on a Galaxy Nexus, I don't see options menu because by default it doesn't have options menu button. How can I show options menu button in my App for only Galaxy Nexus? With other phones it's fine, and I can get options Menu.

Comment: What's your build target?

Comment: Jelly Bean 4.1 and above

Answer (score 14):

In Android 3.0, Google switched from having a dedicated menu key to using the `ActionBar` for menu functionality.  If your build target is 3.0 or above, your menu will default to using the `ActionBar`.

If there is a menu key on the phone, any run over options that are usually shown by the three dots icon in the action bar will instead show up with the menu button.  If there is no menu key on the phone, all options will be shown on the action bar.  Because the menu key is going away, it is encouraged that you utilize the `ActionBar` class for your menus from 3.0 and beyond.

Now, older apps that run on new platforms without a menu key will generate a fake menu key next to the recent apps button.  This makeshift menu key will only appear if your build target is 2.3.4 or below since it's only there for backwards compatibility reasons. (edit: build target should be anything less than, or including API 13)

In your case, you should utilize the `ActionBar` for your menu since you're building against a newer version of Android.  If you're worried about backwards compatibility then you can always utilize a library such as ActionBarSherlock to use the action bar on older platforms.

Comment: My pleasure.  Be sure to accept an answer if it meets your needs so that others might benefit from the information.

Comment: Turns out @nicopico is correct and the CMoS button is available for build targets up to 13 (3.2), not just up to 8 (2.3.4)

Answer (score 5):

You need to think about why you want an "options" button - this is an old, poor pattern, which has been superceded by the `ActionBar` which really is much nicer.

But you might need it, for client reasons (like I needed to keep it in for the client). If that's the case, then you can follow my advice below (slightly edited from original that mistakely mentioned "action bar")

---

You can set your `build target` to a version before ICS (i.e. up to and including API 13 / HoneyComb 3.2).

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="7"
    android:targetSdkVersion="13" />
```

That will get the system to use a compatibility mode setting that inserts an `overflow` icon into your phone's bottom button bar - this should provide the functionality you are after. Pressing this button will have the same response as pressing a "menu" button on the Samsung Galaxy S2 for example.

---

Here you can see the compatibility "options" button, and the menu that has been shown when it was pressed:

[image: ICS compatibility options button on Galaxy Nexus]

---

### Note:

As other commentators mention, you should consider the better choice of the `ActionBar` pattern. If you want backwards compatibility, then I recommend the Action Bar Sherlock library.

But if you are looking for a quick fix, or the client can't afford a big refactor to move to the Action Bar pattern, then this is the way to do it.

Comment: But then you cannot use any of the nice features added by ICS or JellyBean

Answer (score 4):

If you use the [Action Bar](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/actionbar.html), the option menu is replaced by the overflow. 
If not, you have to implement a button yourself, somewhere in your own application.

The menu button (otherwise known as *Compatibility Menu of Shame*) is only displayed in the System bar for application targeting API 13 or lower

Here is a way to check if the device has a hardware menu key.

```
// Menu key
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH) {
    hasPermanentMenuKey = hasPermanentMenuKey(context.getApplicationContext());
}
else {
    // No way to know for sure...
    // All devices before Honeycomb should have a menu key. 
    // Honeycomb device usually don't have one
    hasPermanentMenuKey = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB;
}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH)
private boolean hasPermanentMenuKey(Context context) {
    return ViewConfiguration.get(context).hasPermanentMenuKey();
}
```

Comment: Love the name for the compatibility menu.  I will be using this from now on.

Answer (score 2):

Options menu is stopped from android version 3.x (Honeycomb). Therefor it is not mandatory that option menu button to be present on latest phones. So go for action bar. You can use `Sherlock ActionBar` library to support action bar in all platform.

**Update :** User **ActionBarCompat**