# How to add menuItem dynamicaly in sherlockaction bar?

Tags: android

So I've been working on and Android app that  has a Sherlock action Bar on the top  and that part is working fine but now I want to be able to dynamically add Menu Items to the Sherlock  Action Bar. 
I have to display log in name on screen if user is log in. 
Suppose on Activity A I have Log in Button. When that button is clicked then LoginActivity starts. After log in B activity is start. If user pressed back button from activity B then Activity A again starts. But menu items name is not displays. For that I am using onCreateOptionsMenu method.

Comment: in what activity you want to show logged user name? A, Login, B? You want to show name as a title?

Comment: In activity A. I am using getSupportMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.home_menu, menu); in onCreateOptionsMenu method.\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this should help you:
[What onPrepareOptionsMenu do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16758517/what-onprepareoptionsmenu-do)

i.e., use onPrepareOptionsMenu() method