# Change android build target eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, build, target

I have an android app that I've been working on for a while. I recently found that on phones such as the nexus the menu button does not appear. According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15250024/show-options-menu-button-on-galaxy-nexus-android-4-1), the menu button is deprecated for that version of android and my options are to either implement the action bar or change my build target to a lower one. Due to time constraints I wanted to change the build target as a temporary fix until I get the time to implement the action bar.

I followed the instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342739/how-to-change-target-build-on-android-project), but when I get to the Android section in properties I don't have any other options for Build Targets. The only option available is 4.2.2, and I need 2.3.4 or lower. What can I do to change the build target or is implementing the Action Bar my only option?

Comment: Have you downloaded the previous APIs using the SDK Manager?

Comment: Download the required api from the sdk manager http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15804261/unable-to-resolve-target-android-15/15804314#15804314

Comment: @Apoorv Well, I sure feel silly. That fixed the problem. It ended up causing a bunch of problems in my code though so I'm going to have to just go ahead and implement the action bar sooner instead. Thanks for your help!